# How KeyValueStore allows write operations (Kafka Streams)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to understand kafka stream's `Statestore`. I understood some basics of it. I looked into the code.

**Here is the declaration of `StateStore`:**

```
public interface StateStore { }
```

One of the interfaces which extends `StateStore` is `KeyValueStore`.

**Here is the declaration of `KeyValueStore`:**

```
public interface KeyValueStore<K, V> extends StateStore, ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<K, V> { }
```

**Here is the declaration of `ReadOnlyKeyValueStore`:**

```
public interface ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<K, V> { }
```

My doubt is this:

```
public interface KeyValueStore<K, V> extends StateStore, ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<K, V> { }
```

How `KeyValueStore` is allowing the following operations (taken from its java-doc_):

> /**

- A key-value store that supports put/get/delete and range queries.
- 
- @param  The key type
- @param  The value type
  */

`KeyValueStore` is extending `ReadOnlyKeyValueStore`. So how is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an interface, there's no logic that explicitly limits the ability to write.

The only difference is the addition of the put and delete method(s). The get method is obtained through inheritance of the read-only store interface

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/KeyValueStore.java#L40

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is what is confusion. On one side it is extending that "Readonly" contract, and there is contradicting implementation (put / delete )..

Comment: True. There's not really a better way to express that, though :)

Comment: You should not see it as "limitation" but as feature set. A super class/inferface offers a reduced feature set that is extended by sub-classes/interfaces. That is how Java (or object oriented programming) works in general.